# please can you tell me how to solve parameter count mismatch on this code? i am using QT 4.13.1

Tags: sqlite, qt

there is the source code.

```
    db=QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    db.setDatabaseName("C:/Users/Overlord/Documents/Qt Project/Projet_de_Genie_Logiciel/database.db");
    db.open();
    if(db.isOpen()){
        QSqlQuery qry(db);
        qry.prepare("INSERT INTO projet (ID, theme, participant, classe, annee, jury, note, taux_de_completion, Description) VALUES(:ID, :theme, :participant, :classe, :annee, :encadreur, :jury, :note, :taux, :description);");
                    qry.bindValue(":theme",theme );
                    qry.bindValue(":partcipant",participant );
                    qry.bindValue(":ID",4 );
                    qry.bindValue(":classe",classe );
                    qry.bindValue(":annee", annee);
                    qry.bindValue(":encadreur",encadreur );
                    qry.bindValue(":jury", jury);
                    qry.bindValue(":note", note);
                    qry.bindValue(":taux",taux );
                    qry.bindValue(":description",description );
                   if(!qry.exec()){
                        QSqlError er;
                        er=qry.lastError();
                        qDebug()<<er.text();
                    }
```

i want to save those data in a data base. but after the execution, i receive Parameter count mismatch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`encadreur` is in the VALUES list, but not in the INSERT columns list.